# rxswift- getting into the dispose bag after the first time error

Tags: swift, rx-swift

each time there is an error, I'm getting into the dispose  bag and can't enter even with a good password

need your help

```
self.loginViewModel.performLogin(email: email, password: password)
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
            .subscribe(onNext: { _ in
                self.loginSucceeded()
            }, onError: { error in
                self.loginFailed(withError: error as? ApiError)
            }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Observable contract is that and Observable will emit zero ore more `next` events and then a stop event which is either a `completed` or `error`. Once the observable emits an error, any subscriptions listening to it are done and will be disposed of. This is non-negotiable.

In order to keep the subscription alive, the ultimate source must **not** error. The easiest way to do that is to catch the error within a flatMap and convert it into something else.

Here is a typical login subscription as an example:

```
// in viewDidLoad or a function called from it:
loginButton.rx.tap
    .withLatestFrom(Observable.combineLatest(emailTextField.rx.text.orEmpty, passwordTextField.rx.text.orEmpty))
    .flatMapLatest { [viewModel] (email, password) in
        viewModel!.performLogin(email: email, password: password)
            .map { Result.success($0) }
            .catchError { Observable.just(Result.failure($0)) }
    }
    .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] result in
        switch result {
        case .success:
            self?.loginSucceeded()
        case .failure(let error):
            self?.loginFailed(withError: error as? ApiError)
        }
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

The above subscription will stay alive for as long as the view controller exists, even if the network produces an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.loginViewModel.performLogin(email: email, password: password)
                .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
                .filter({ $0 != nil })
                .subscribe{ _ in
                    self.loginSucceeded()
            }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
            self.loginViewModel.observeError()
                .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
                .subscribe{
                    self.loginFailed(withError: $0.element as? ApiError)
            }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

thanks @Daniel- this is my soultuin